# React Native EventEmitter not registering Events

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, react-native, spotify

We are trying to repair a critical failure in an open source library for React Native Spotify by converting a method from using a callback to use React Native EventEmitter.

Unfortunately our events are not being registered and are receiving this error message in xcode: `'TestEvent' is not a supported event type for RCTEventEmitter. Supported events are: '(null)'`

We have reviewed the documentation on how to implement a NativeEventEmitter and I believe we are following it pretty closely. The problem I think is with Objective-C and how we are including our `EventManager` class, the JavaScript side of this is really simple.

`// SpotifyLoginViewController.m`

```
#import "SpotifyLoginViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SpotifyAuth.h"

@interface SpotifyLoginViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic) NSURL *login;

@end

@implementation SpotifyLoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                                configuration:configuration];
    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    _webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_login]];
    self.view = _webView;

}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
      id<RCTBridgeDelegate> module = [[EventManager alloc] init];
      RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:module launchOptions:nil];

      SpotifyAuth *sharedManager = [SpotifyAuth sharedManager];
      NSURL *url = navigationAction.request.URL;
      NSString *myScheme = [[sharedManager myScheme] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"://callback" withString:@""];
      if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:myScheme]) {

        RCTEventEmitter *event = [[RCTEventEmitter alloc] init];
        event.bridge = bridge;
        [event sendEventWithName:@"TestEvent" body:@{@"name":@"metallica"}];

        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        return;
      }
      decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
```

`// EventManager.h`

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>


@interface EventManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

- (NSURL*)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge*)bridge;

@end
```

`//  EventManager.m`

```
#import "EventManager.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation EventManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"TestEvent"];
}

- (NSURL*)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge*)bridge {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  return jsCodeLocation;  // [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios"];
}

@end
```

`// player.js`

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
const eventManager = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.EventManager);

subscription = eventManager.addListener('TestEvent', (data) => {
  console.log('the event fired!');
  console.log(data);
});
```

We are using RN `0.44.0`

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this eventually?